# How do multiple calculations on a group in pandas and write it to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, jupyter-notebook

please help me with the following task. In my dataframe I try to get the information if feed-providers copy data from another. The placement column represent a sequence about the supplydate of the value. This means 1 is the first (GooFeed) and 2 is second (CyberFeed). The value can occur multiple lists of the same provider. That means the placement itself is not enough and the column multipleSources is needed.

The dataframe I have:

| value | source | placement | multipleSources |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | GooFeed | 1 | 2 |
| A | CyberFeed | 2 | 2 |
| A | GooFeed | 3 | 2 |
| B | AbuseFeed | 1 | 1 |
| B | AbuseFeed | 2 | 1 |
| C | WOWFeed | 1 | 3 |
| C | GooFeed | 2 | 3 |
| C | CyberFeed | 3 | 3 |

The dataframe I need:

| source | second | firstProviders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GooFeed | 1 | [WOWFeed] |
| CyberFeed | 2 | [GOODFeed,WOWFeed] |

The column seconds means every case in which the provider had a feed which was not first and the first had another provider.

I managed to get all the firsts (groupby, lambda where is 1 and sum) but I can not get my head around how this works. It is like the next with multiple calculations and I would be so happy, if anyone could help me out. Even if it is only tips.

Best regards Maurice

Comment: Important information i forgot and I don't know how to edit my post:

Instead of the list in the 'firstProviders' column i would need a dictionary which shows how often which feed was first. In the example it would be:

CyberFeed --- 2 --- {GOODFeed:1,WOWFeed:1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to add the name of the first place of each group as a new column - this allows you to test if the current source is the first provider for each row.

```
df['firstProvider'] = df.groupby('value').source.transform('first')
df.query('placement != 1 and source != firstProvider')
  value     source  placement  multipleSources firstProvider
1     A  CyberFeed          2                2       GooFeed
6     C    GooFeed          2                3       WOWFeed
7     C  CyberFeed          3                3       WOWFeed
```

This assumes the `placement` column is "ordered" as it takes the first row of each group - if not, you can sort before grouping e.g. `.sort_values('placement').groupby('value')`

To get your dict in a column - you can use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

seconds = df.query('placement != 1 and source != firstProvider')
seconds = seconds.groupby('source').firstProvider.agg(Counter).reset_index()

>>> seconds
      source                 firstProvider
0  CyberFeed  {'GooFeed': 1, 'WOWFeed': 1}
1    GooFeed                {'WOWFeed': 1}
```

To get your `second` column you get the `len` of each dict.

```
seconds['second'] = seconds.firstProvider.map(len)

>>> seconds
      source                 firstProvider  second
0  CyberFeed  {'GooFeed': 1, 'WOWFeed': 1}       2
1    GooFeed                {'WOWFeed': 1}       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Everyhting worked fine and I added even some more distinction with another grupby value.
seconds.groupby(['source','domain']).firstProvider.agg(Counter).reset_index()

Comment: What would I have to do to get the Counter of distinct values. Every time it is not first but only once for the value?

I tried to get the .unique operator on Counter. But it does not work together.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for `seconds.groupby('source').firstProvider.unique()`

Comment: Awesome. I managed to get it working. Thank you a lot!